# AWS CDK python bundle with dependencies in requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-cdk

I have been playing with the simple examples in https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/python , all projects starting by lambda-*

However, I haven't seen one example where the aws-lambda handler imports libraries. These libraries are defined in `requirements.txt`

1. how can AWS lambda imports their own  `requirements.txt`
2. if the dependencies cannot be imported. I package them into .zip file .

However the existing methods don't take a .zip  . See this proposal https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6294

The project structure is like this:

```
project/

|
|-- lambda/
|-- lambda/handler.py
|-- lambda/module1.py
|-- lambda/module2.py
|-- lambda/requirements.txt
|
|-- stack/ias_stack.py # define the Infrastructure as code
|
|-- app.py # call "ias_stack" module
| 
|-- requirements.txt
```

I want to deploy tht code + dependencies inside the folder "lambda/"

**How can you import dependencies in your Python AWS-Lambda using CDK ?**

This must be possible.
I've already packaged a JVM code base into .zip . Terraform pushes this .zip into the AWS lambda.

## Searching

After search , I am not the only one facing the issue
[How to install external modules in a Python Lambda Function created by AWS CDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58855739/how-to-install-external-modules-in-a-python-lambda-function-created-by-aws-cdk)

I solved by creating a Lambda Layer. I will post an all inclusive solution.

Answer (score 3):

The `aws-cdk.aws-lambda-python` L2 construct exist specifically for this.

Here's the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-lambda-python-readme.html

Typescript example form the docs above:

```js
import * as lambda from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda";
import { PythonFunction } from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-python";

new PythonFunction(this, 'MyFunction', {
  entry: '/path/to/my/function', // required
  index: 'my_index.py', // optional, defaults to 'index.py'
  handler: 'my_exported_func', // optional, defaults to 'handler'
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_6, // optional, defaults to lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7
});
```

It will install dependencies from a poetry file, a pipfile, or requiremenets.txt

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the `requirements.txt` must exist at the entry path

Comment: Thanks. The lambda code and entry are in different folders.  Yeah, you can put the entry to the root of the project,. `requirements.txt` must also be at the root of entry path. That's not what I want

Comment: Why would the requirements for the CDK app and the lambda be the same? Why does your lambda need to install the CDK?

Comment: @RaymondChenon can you clarify why this answer doesn't work for you?

Comment: @gshpychka , thanks for your contribution .  
I made my lambda run by importing a Lambda layer. I had to create my own layer which contains plenty of Python dependencies ( many unused ).
Your solution didn't import the dependencies in the `requirements.txt`. 
I am looking for a cleaner, simpler solution. Or I will post my Lambda Layer solution which is quite long

Comment: @RaymondChenon my solution does import the dependencies in the `requirements.txt`, so it's the cleanest solution available.

Comment: @gshpychka , I already followed the documentation and put the `requirements.txt` in the entry path ,  it doesn't work. Hence, I had to import my own Lambda layer. 
BTW I upvoted your answer.

Comment: You're doing something wrong, because it definitely does work. Maybe add some code to your question to see why it's not working like it should.

Comment: This library is marked as alpha in v2 of the CDK API. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-lambda-python-alpha-readme.html Needs to be installed separately: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-python-alpha

Comment: I added the comment as additional information for others, as the problem still persists in v2.

Comment: @comfytoday which problem?

Comment: The problem outlined in the question.